# Are Leaflet.js and leaflet-indoors reliant on external map providers?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, leaflet, indoor-positioning-system

I am new to javascript and indoor/outdoor mapping, and I've only been coding for a little over a year,
but I got a job (working for free) as a coder for a startup company that creates indoor location and guidance
systems. This has not been my first task for this company but its the first task that I feel may be a little 
out of my depth but I think I could probably handle it with a little help from the proagramming community!

What I need to do is create an interactive indoor location map that displays in real time the locations
of various people and things on the map. It is to be part of an indoor location and tracking systems. The
locations of things are gotten using static bluetooth beacons located around the building that recieve 
information from bluetooth tags that will be attatched to the person or thing that is being tracked.

I would like if you could clear up some things related to Leaflet.js and leaflet-indoor.

From what I have researched, it seems leaflet relies on external map providers such as OpenStreetMap or
Mapbox, and uses geojson data to interact with those maps. An indoor map would be an extra layer, a geojson feature array, 
sitting on top of the other map layer. Leaflet/Leaflet-indoor then allows you to create the interactivity of that map.

I will probably need to have an indoor map of a building on its own, without any surrounding areas, it looks to that when
using the above APIs, you have to have your indoor map sitting over a full outdoor map. If I was to create my own SVG maps
with Illustrator or Inkscape, would it be possible to use Leaflet to create the interactivity of that map? Would I still have
to use geojson to create the coordinate references for the walls and paths of that map? Or is there a way to only display the
indoor map and remove the surrounding areas with leaflet?

I think I'm leaning more towards creating my own SVG maps and trying to interact with them using javascript, with or without Leaflet.
I know Leaflet has a plugin for live tracking of objects using [Leaflet-realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime),
so it would be really great if i could incorporate this into my indoor system. As i think it just needs to be fed lat-long data
for the tracking.

Comment: Hi, I have been making my own map app using my own picture maps. Leaflet is able to work with custom map tiles! I have followed this guide (http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/), just that I did some trial and error with the zoom levels to make sure the map showed up. 


As for Leaflet indoor, it uses geoJson, so it won't be applicable. That said, you don't need it at all. Under layer control (http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html), the demo shows how to render different base layers (floors). The button is on the top right hand corner to change layers.

Comment: By 'leaflet-indoor', do you mean https://github.com/cbaines/leaflet-indoor?

Comment: What does make a specific map (tile) provider 'external' to you?